# Regex 'find' returns 2 entries

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a requirement to list all files in a URL and am using jsoup based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516080/groovy-file-handling-from-http-url)
The file names are in this format - MB-2014-04-13-07_12_22.log.2
my question is why the variable 'file' inside the .each method has 2 entries with the same value (MB-2014-04-13-07_12_22.log.2) whereas the 'println fileName' correctly prints only once?

```
        def (doc,files, dirs) = [Jsoup.connect(logFolder).get(),[],[]]
        doc.select("body pre a").each { a->
        def fileName = a.attr('href')
        println fileName
        (fileName =~ /(.*?\.log(.*?)\.(\d?))/).each{file->
            def fileUrl = logFolder+file[0];
            println fileUrl;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you gain from:

```
fileName =~ /(.*?\.log(.*?)\.(\d?))/
```

is a object of type **Matcher**

```
groovy> println (fileName =~ /(.*?\.log(.*?)\.(\d?))/) 
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(.*?\.log(.*?)\.(\d?)) region=0,28 lastmatch=]
```

and your ***file*** is pointing to list of groups of the regex:

```
[MB-2014-04-13-07_12_22.log.2, MB-2014-04-13-07_12_22.log.2, , 2]
```

First element is first pair of parenthesis, second element is second pair of parenthesis and so on (zero element is whole expression).

Some more info about regex in Groovy is [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions)

Comment: Thank you very much. found the follwoing in the link shared."// In 1.5, each iteration would always return a string of the entire match, ignoring groups.
// In 1.6, if the regex has any groups, it returns a list of Strings as shown above." is this your explanation?